# Find the number of straight lines which satisfy the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx}+x(\frac{dy}{dx})^2-y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the number of straight lines which satisfy the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx}+x(\frac{dy}{dx})^2-y=0$.

---

As the order of the differential equation is one, so let $y=mx$ be the solution of the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx}+x(\frac{dy}{dx})^2-y=0$.
$\frac{d(mx)}{dx}+x(\frac{d(mx)}{dx})^2-mx=0$
$m+m^2x-mx=0$
I am stuck here.I do not know how to find the number of straight lines.

Comment: Since your last equation must be true for all $x$, the only possibility is $m=0$.  However from the beginning you should also have considered lines $y=mx+c$.  This will perhaps give more solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $y=mx+c$.  Working as you have done gives
$$m+m^2x-mx-c=0\ .$$
Since this must be true for all $x$ we have
$$m^2-m=0\quad\hbox{and}\quad m-c=0\ ,$$
which gives the possibilities $m=0$, $c=0$ or $m=1$, $c=1$.  So there are two possible lines
$$y=0\quad\hbox{and}\quad y=x+1\ .$$